# Translate Language Alfresco Community 5.1 to other languages

Tags: alfresco, aikau

In `..\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\share\imports\share-header.lib.js`:

```
{
         id: "HEADER_SHARED_FILES",
         name: "alfresco/menus/AlfMenuBarItem",
         config: {
            id: "HEADER_SHARED_FILES",
            label: "header.menu.shared.label",
            targetUrl: "context/shared/sharedfiles"
         }
      },
```

But in File `share-header.lib.properties` I don't find

```
header.menu.shared.label=Shared Files
```

How do I translate this?

Comment: Did you try reading the [Alfresco translations wiki page](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Language_Packs) and the [Alfresco community translations page](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Community_Translations)?

Answer (score 1):

That particular message key is part of [Aikau](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau) and is translated within it. If you wish to provide additional language pack support for Aikau then you should read [this](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/wiki/Additional-Language-Pack-Support).